# ASP.NET faster upload

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-core, websocket

I am recording voice on xamarin client and sending to asp.net core server.
But sending takes long time when I have long audio record.
How can I speed it up?

1. send audio record by chunks (for example 16kB) while recording audio

   - use some temporary in-memory database for it
   - or put it into postgreSQL into some temp. table?
2. use websocket instead of web api which should support chunking

   - use SignalR for this request?

Comment: Would compressing the chunks help?

Comment: thanks for idea, I am experimenting with GzipStream and BSON